# Java Swift 2 OSX How do I set System Properties and Authenticator?

Tags: java, macos, swift2, system-properties

I can set app specific properties with `NSUserDefaults`, but not System Properties such as proxxy/port.

Her'e how I do it in Java. How can I do this with Swift 2?

```
// Set proxy/port in system properties
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "12.345.67.89");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "1234");
System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");

// Authenticate
System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", "someusername");    
System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", "somepassword");

System.setProperty("http.proxySet", "true");
```

Comment: Is this a sandboxed .app, and what was the behavior when you tried setting the values in Swift?

Comment: That's my question. How do you set system properties in swift? The Java is standard in any app I make that requires proxy.

Comment: Sandboxed boxed apps won't allow changing `NSUserDefaults` for any application other than itself.

Comment: Then how do I set proxy and port and authorize credentials?

Comment: There's no simple answer to that; I would start by reading the [Apple App Sandbox Design Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/DesigningYourSandbox/DesigningYourSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH4-SW6) then take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10765768), and go from there. Some apps just aren't good candidates for sandboxing and the developers often offer them outside of the App Store.

Comment: Are you sure? This is OSX btw. Not iOS. The reason I switched from doing this in iOS to OS X is because o know for sure it can be done. I've done it in Java on OS X.

Comment: Apparently you don't read. If you're sure it can be done then why would you ask this question, it makes no sense...

Comment: I "read" everything. Perhaps there's more than that explanation for me not understanding? Perhaps you're not being clear, or I'm not understanding what you're saying. If you'd be so kind, could you clarify?

Comment: But yes, I'll read the documentation again. Thank you.

Comment: I think it's you not being clear, as you never even answered the question in my first comment.

Comment: No it's not sandboxed.

Comment: I won't even ask why you didn't mention that this entire discussion.

Comment: Because I thought you used the wrong word and meant "playgrounds". I was not aware of what sandbox meant. Thank you, I appreciate the link.

Comment: Now that you mention it, *Apple* used the wrong word; I can see how someone *might* confuse the meaning of Sandbox v Playground, although in computing the term "Sandbox" is always associated with the security mechanism for separating running programs.

Comment: To answer your question, yes system settings can be manipulated if the app is not in a sandbox.

Comment: I mentioned how yesterday, although it appears you abandoned [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38413748/swift-2-osx-how-do-i-implement-proxy-settings-with-nsurlsession) and created another one.

Comment: I switched to NSURLSession and added configuration but that didn't work.

Comment: I'll repost that code with your suggestion when o get home tomorrow.

Comment: Your comment on that thread doesn't answer how to set system preferences. Also, I followed up with a question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117624/discussion-between-dbconfession-and-lll).